# How do you prove that $M(N)=O(N^{1/2+\epsilon})$ from the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, mellin-transform

I understand that if $M(N)=O(N^\sigma)$, then 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ and therefore
$$
 \frac{1}{s\zeta(s)} = \int_0^\infty M(x) x^{-(s+1)} dx $$
for $s>\sigma$, and that having $\sigma=1/2+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ will thus prove the RH.

The Wikipedia article on the [Mertens Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture) states that the reverse also holds, but I don't understand the details of argument:

> Using the Mellin inversion theorem we now can express M in terms of 1/ζ as
>
> $$M(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \frac{x^s}{s \zeta(s)}\, ds$$
>   which is valid for $1 < \sigma < 2$, and valid for $1/2 < \sigma < 2$ on the Riemann hypothesis.

Here is my first problem. It seems to me we can only extend this formula if $$\lim_{T \to \pm \infty} \frac{x^{\sigma+iT}}{(\sigma+iT)\zeta(\sigma+iT)}= 0$$ uniformly on the strip $1/2 < \sigma < 2$. If this is indeed necessary, is there an easy way to show this without
invoking heavy machinery?

> From this, the Mellin transform integral must be convergent,

Again this seems to need the limit above (in order for the Mellin inversion theorem to apply).

> and hence $M(x)$ must be $O(x^e)$ for every exponent e greater than $1/2$.

This is also very unclear to me. There are certainly functions $f(x)$ such
that
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-(s+1)} dx$$
converges but $f(x)$ is not $O(x^e)$ for every $e>1/2$. Take for instance

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}x &\mbox{if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is a power of two} \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

for which the integral is convergent, but $f(x)$ is not $O(x^e)$ for any $e<1$. By using that $|M(n)-M(n-1)| \le 1$, I've managed to prove that
$M(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^e)$ for $e>0.75$ but I still need $e>0.5$.

Or am I misinterpreting this and should I get that from the vertical line
Mellin integral?

> From this it follows that
>
> $$M(x) = O(x^{\frac12+\epsilon})$$

Comment: Note you say, ".. then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$." That is not a consequence of the first statement; it is true for all $s$ where the left side converges.

Comment: Certainly, but the requirement that $M(N)=O(N^e)$ is sufficient for convergence of the LHS when $\mbox{Re}(s)>e$.

Comment: it is detailed in [Titchmarsh's book](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf) (the last chapter consequences of the RH), But at first you should look at page.60 to 66 where the same idea is applied to show $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) = 1 \implies M(x) = o(x)$

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Titchmarsh's book "The theory of the Riemann zeta-function" for this one, as pointed out by reuns:

http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/The%20Theory%20Of%20The%20Riemann%20Zeta-Function%20-Titshmarch.pdf

The argument you're looking for is given in ch.14.25, p.370, in Theorem 14.25(C), using the inverse Mellin transform on region $\sigma>1$, particularly with $\sigma=2$.

Best regards.